How to send Newrelic custom parameter when using NextJS?
I am using NextJS version 12 and Newrelic 8.7.1, from my package.json
    "newrelic": "^8.7.1",
    "next": "12",

const isProd = process.env.APP_ENV === 'production';
if (isProd) {
    require('newrelic');
}


This is working great and I can see events under Transaction in newrelic.
I want to add more custom parameters now, for example

app_version which I have under process.env.APP_VERSION
x_request_id which I receive only via some AJAX calls
user_id when logged in from the session
...etc

Can I achieve this without ejecting/using custom nextjs server ?
If the answer is no, please point me to any solution on how to do this.
This is crucial for accurate monitoring.
Thank you in advance
